# PostgreSQL not using index scan over GIN index on JSONB

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a table in PostgreSQL containig one JSONB column. The JSON looks like this-  `{'key':some_key, 'value': some_value}`.
I indexed `key` in JSON using -

```
CREATE INDEX t3_index ON t3 USING GIN ((data->'key'));
```

The table's schama looks like-

```
                Table "public.t3"
 Column | Type  | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-------+-----------+----------+---------
 data   | jsonb |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "t3_index" gin ((data -> 'key'::text))
```

When I query using `key`, PostgreSQL is doing a sequnetial scan.

```
psql_eth=> explain (analyze, buffers) select * from t3 where data->>'key'='ZGJVcGdyYWRlXzIwMTcwNzE0ZGVkdXBsaWNhdGVEYXRh';
                                             QUERY PLAN                                             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t3  (cost=0.00..4201.65 rows=377 width=289) (actual time=0.017..42.976 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: ((data ->> 'key'::text) = 'ZGJVcGdyYWRlXzIwMTcwNzE0ZGVkdXBsaWNhdGVEYXRh'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 75049
   Buffers: shared hit=3142
 Planning time: 0.068 ms
 Execution time: 42.996 ms
(6 rows)
```

1. Why is PostgreSQL doing seq scan?
2. How can I make the query result faster? How to make it use GIN index?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just `explain`)

Comment: The optimizer assumes the table only has 334 rows so a seq scan is the natural choice. It seems your statistics are not up-to-date. Does the plan change after you run `analyze t4`?

Comment: no, only visible difference is rows=351 (total number of rows changed in meanwhile by few 1000s). 
`select count(*) from t4` gives `712313`
Why/how does it assume 334 rows?

Comment: `Execution time: 42.996 ms` You want it faster? BTW what was your table's name? t3 <> t4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING)

> The default GIN operator class for jsonb supports queries with top-level key-exists operators ?, ?& and ?| operators and path/value-exists operator @>.

The index is not applicable for the equality operator (=). You can use simple btree index instead:

```
create index on t3 ((data->>'key'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but if it still helps, see below.

You have used `CREATE INDEX t3_index ON t3 USING GIN ((data->'key'));`

Like the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) says -

> for type jsonb, **jsonb_ops** is the default.

Since you have not provided any operator class, the default is choosen for you.

For `jsonb_ops` operator class the only supported Operators are -

> ? ?& ?| @> @? @@

`=` is not in above list and hence not supported i.e the index can not be used.

You can instead change your where clause to use `@>` and try again -

```
explain (analyze, buffers) select * from t3 where data @> "{'key':'ZGJVcGdyYWRlXzIwMTcwNzE0ZGVkdXBsaWNhdGVEYXRh'}" ; 
// i have not tried the syntax or quotes usage - but something using @> will definitely work.
```

For small tables - planner might still choose Seq Scan as it could be faster. But since you have said your table has `712313` rows, the `@>` approach will definitely make use of GIN index.